# What's the benefit of generics in an in interface e.g. IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>

Tags: c#, interfaces, generics

I've come across a method that requires a parameter that implements IEnumerable and is of a certain type like this:

```
public myMethod (IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> myParameter) {
                   ....
}
```

Why do this at all? Why not just implement the IEnumerable interface for HttpPostedFileBase and require the parameter to be an HTTPostedFileBase?

Comment: Because `IEnumerable<T>` can be used for any type, not just `HttpPostedFileBase`.  That's generally true for the concrete implementations of `IEnumerable<T>` such as `List<T>` and Dictionary `<Tkey, TValue>`.  In other words, you don't need a concrete implementation of each of these collections for every possible type; you only need *one* implementation for all types.

Comment: Also, it gives your caller more flexibility.  If you make your type enumerable, you have to supply the way for your caller to add multiples to it.  If you use IEnumerable<T>, you leave your caller free to pass a List<T> or a HashSet<T> or a Queue<T> or a Stack<T> or a host of other things.  This lets your caller choose what's best for his/her circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because then `IEnumerable<T>` can be used for any type T, not just `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Most of the collections in the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace implement `IEnumerable<T>`. `IEnumerable<T>` was created, not to provide concrete collection implementations for specific types, but to provide concrete implementations of specific kinds of collections *that can work with any type.*

The following collections all implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and can therefore perform all of the operations defined by `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
HashSet<T>
List<T>
LinkedList<T>
Queue<T>
SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>
SortedList<TKey, TValue>
Stack<T>
SynchronizedCollection<T>
SynchronizedKeyedCollection<K, T>
SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

But while they all have different performance and memory characteristics, they're all still capable of working with objects of any type.

Comment: Doh. Thanks Robert. Yes, that answers the question so I'll mark it as such. You've helped me recognise what my real question should've been! It's here - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/315784/c-how-can-a-parameter-be-an-ienumerable

Comment: That question no longer exists.  I guess you realized that you can call SaveLogo with any concrete instantiated type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Robert, I was being a dumdum. I was misreading the code but you've clarified things with your answer. Obviously what the method expects is a concrete instance of anything that implements IEnumerable and that contains items of type HttpPostedFileBase - that's what I missed!